# Assign class to Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using Html.BeginForm but when trying to assign to it a class there is a problem. If i use class  for the fourth place is fine. But if i try to use enctype in addition, there is a error.
This is fine:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
```

But this is not:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}, new { @class = "listForm" } ))
```

And this is not:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "listForm" },  new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
```

Any ideas please. Thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "listForm", enctype ="multipart/form-data"  })`  Try that

EDIT:

enctype and class are both htmlAttributes so you should place them in one anonymous object.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, it does the job.